# How to properly retrieve dotnet non-specific runtime identifier?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I would like to get the RID without the version part in the dotnet application. For example, if the RID returned by `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.RuntimeIdentifier` is `win10-x64` the "non-specific" runtime ID would be `win-x64`.

I could build this string using `IsOSPlatform()` function and `ProcessArchitecture` or parse the actual RID, but in the [.NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) it is not adviced:

> Don't try to parse RIDs to retrieve component parts.

> Don't build RIDs programmatically.

Another idea would be to retrieve the `-r` parameter from `dotnet publish`, but I was not able to find a way to do that as well.

Comment: As far as the RID catalog is concerned there is no "non-specific" identifier, or rather there is no *single* such identifier. `win10-x64` has import parents `win10` and `win81-x64`, for example. There is no way you could get to `win-x64` from there to know that is "the" non-specific identifier: why not `win`, for example, the parent of that, or indeed `win10`, the parent without a specific platform?

Comment: For the "non-specific" I meant the identifiers under "not version-specific" category (for Windows and MacOS) and "not distribution-specific" (Linux). But the question could be more general, how to get the identifiers of parents without recreating manually entire graph?

Comment: Well, that was sort of my point, even recreating the graph won't really help you in the sense that you can't pinpoint the node `win-x64` as the node you want. Of course the [`Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms) lib does contain all the code used to generate RIDs from runtime groups (and the base data); even though they don't want you generating RIDs programmatically, that is the canonical code to generate RIDs programmatically, so if anything's reliable that is. :P

Comment: This PowerShell command might help get you somewhere: `"$($IsWindows ? 'win' : $IsMacOS ? 'osx' : 'linux')-$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::OSArchitecture.ToString().ToLower())"`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue for a discovery service for automate updates.
End up creating a class like this:

```
public static class ServiceIdentification
{
    public static string? Name => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;

    public static string Version
    {
        get
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            // Get the AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute
            var informationalVersionAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
                assembly,
                typeof(AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute)
                ) as AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute;

            // Extract the version from the attribute
            string packageVersion = informationalVersionAttribute?.InformationalVersion ?? string.Empty;
            SemanticVersion version = SemanticVersion.Parse(packageVersion);
            return version.ToNormalizedString();
        }
    }

    private static string OSIdentifier
    {
        get
        {
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)) return "win";
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux)) return "linux";
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX)) return "osx";
            return "unknown";
        }
    }

    public static string BasicRID => $"{OSIdentifier}-{RuntimeInformation.ProcessArchitecture.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()}";
```

Use like this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{ServiceIdentification.Name} {ServiceIdentification.Version} {ServiceIdentification.BasicRID}");
```